# Two views of one controller presenting the same data in different ways - possible using storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, uistoryboard

I have a controller that will send a set of data to the view. This set of data must be viewable in two different ways (no, this is not about landscape/portrait), thus two different views. My question is, how do I create these two views, linked to one controller, using storyboard? I want to be able to see and edit both views without doing any ugly tricks.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it gets a bit messy when trying to deal with different "main" views in the context of one controller no matter what you do.

Basically you need to create another view right on top of your `UIViewController`'s view in storyboard and make it hidden, connect its outlets to the controller and when a button that flips your presentation styles gets hit you need to either show or hide your second representation view like this:

```
- (void)btnAction:(id)sender {
  self.secondView.hidden = !self.secondView.hidden;
}
```